# Multiple task execution in Single Formula

Tags: sql, postgresql

My Data consists of 2500 rows and 2 columns

```
iner    tert
41.6    7.19
43.1    7.06
44.5    4.02
45.6    3.81
45.9    7.85
46.2    5.02
47.1    6.12
52.6    5.12
61.1    8.19
68.2    10.14
72.1    12.41
79.8    6.19
81.1    7.18
```

Description

- select maximum tert value as max and minimum tert value as min where
  iner between 43 and 79 and apply formula `(max+min)/2+min as reip`
- select the tert where iner nearer to 45 as r45 and
- select the tert where iner nearer to 72 as r72

Apply Formula

```
700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r45)*40
```

- output  value as repw

and i want to display reip value and repw value as output

I tried it in PostGreSQL

```
Select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip from table_name where iner between 43 and 79
```

This is working but i dont know to apply this reip value in `700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r40)*40` in this formula and how to get the ouput value display as reip and repw

I tried this query it's not working..

```
select reip, 700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r45)*40 as reipw
from ( 
  select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip, tert where iner=44.5 as r45, tert where iner=71.9 as r72
  from  table_name
  where iner between 650 and 800
) as SE_23693370
```

Pls Help me to do this task at single execution....
    ;

Comment: @Crescent Moon Sir, How to do this task in single execution....I tried it in different query, its working , how to do this task in single query execution

Comment: @Arion Sir, Pls Help me how to do this task in single execution...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
select reip, reip+1 as example
from ( 
  select (MAX(tert)+MIN(tert))/2+MIN(tert) as reip
  from  table_name
  where iner between 43 and 79
) as SE_23693370 
;
```

Here is a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/0ad8f/2

Comment: Sir i want to take the value of reip from formula i already tried and i apply that value in this formula **700+(reip-r45)/(r72-r40)*40** after execution of 1st find reip and 2nd find output of repw, then i want to display both values reip and reipw... SE_23693370- means what? How u r using this one? The output it provides after applying formula, it gives wrong value

Comment: Put your own formula (which uses reip) where it has `reip+1`. This is just an example. I can't do it all for you.

Comment: How to use this select statements ** Select reflectance where wavelength=41.6 as r42 ** and ** Select reflectance where wavelength=72.1 as r72 ** in second formula and apply in single execution